# BoldReports - ReportHelper.GetParametersWithValues() returns parameter collection with empty values

Tags: reportviewer, syncfusion

BoldReports ReportViewer Controller:

I'm using the ReportHelper.GetParametersWithValues() function in the OnReportLoaded() method to retrieve the report parameters. It is successfully retrieving the list of parameters, however, only the name attributes are populated - the values are null.

```
private ReportParameterInfoCollection _rptParamColl;

public void OnReportLoaded(ReportViewerOptions reportOption)
{
    _rptParamColl = ReportHelper.GetParametersWithValues(jsonArray, this, _cache);

    if (_rptParamColl != null)
    {
        foreach (ReportParameterInfo rptParam in _rptParamColl)
        {
            if (rptParam.Name == "OrgID")
            {
                if (rptParam.Values != null )
                {
                    // perform appropriate validation on rptParam.Values[0]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the code sample above, rptParam.Name has a value, but the rptParam.Values is null. I know the values exist, as when I inspect the jsonArray object, they are in there (although oddly, after calling ReportHelper.GetParametersWithValues(), the jsonArray object is cleared? Same also happens when calling ReportHelper.GetDataSources(). This is also a problem, as I want to call both methods, and after calling one, cannot call the other... )

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Using the PostReportAction method you can get the client-side parameter value. Please refer to the below code snippet,

```
public object PostReportAction([FromBody] Dictionary<string, object> jsonResult)
{
    if (jsonResult.ContainsKey("parameters") && jsonResult["parameters"] != null)
    {
        var parameterValues = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BoldReports.Web.ReportParameterInfoCollection>(jsonResult["parameters"].ToString());
    }

    return ReportHelper.ProcessReport(jsonResult, this, this._cache);
}
```